# Build standalone Libtiff (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, libtiff

First of all a short disclaimer:
I just started programming in c++ and I just started using Linux (Ubuntu) for developing. If it was for me I would delay this, but I cannot. Time to learn something new!

Scope:
I need to develop a software which does some changes to a set of TIFF images. The algorithm seems to be working on a set of "fake" raster files. Now I need to load a TIFF image, turn it to RGB, apply the algorithm, get back to TIFF and save.
I'm trying to use LibTiff to do so.

Problem:
I need to use a standalone version of the libtiff library because I will need to Build&Run my software as guest on another machine. I can't install libraries there, so I need a pre-build one which I can directly include from my c++ code.

As an example I'd like to have something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "libtiffBin/tiffio.h" //Points to the standalone library and uses it  
int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
  TIFF* tiff; 
  tiff = TIFFOpen ("samples/sample.tif", "r"); 
  TIFFClose (tiff); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can download libtiff source code [here](http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/). Download and extract the version you want. Navigate to the extracted directory and run `./configure` and `make` to compile library. The `./libtiff/.libs/` directory contains the `libtiff.a` static library that can be included in your executable. To compile your executable use `gcc main.c libtiff.a -lz -ljpeg -lm`. Make sure you use the header files that correspond with your compiled library.